# Will i get rewarded for feeding a fasting person in ramadan even if i get paid for it?

Tags: sawm, ramadan

I was wondering something, my father owns a restaurant and our food is halal. we work during ramadan and we open just before maghrib so we have a lot of muslims come to break their fast and to eat. if  i give my customers their food, do i get the reward for feeding a fasting person like prophet Muhammad said in a hadith even though they pay me for the food?

Comment: If you feed paying customers in a restaurant, you get your pay. What else reward are you claiming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feeding entails giving food from your personal resources as a donation. You are rewarded for showing generosity towards a fasting person. If you're selling it, you're not feeding them, you're just doing business to earn money.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you get your  reward  only if you don't record or  show people, including  the one who later you to go feed them and remember  not to use the money given unto your own issues if you were given ten thousand make sure all the money goes to feeding those in the fast